# Create a new custom field for all posts based on current custom field

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I have a custom field for a large number of posts that contains the url for a youtube video. I used to grab the ID from the video and use that to build the thumb but in a new version I'm actually using download_url() for the custom built thumb image url from youtube and downloading it to my server. So I have to do this for all posts in my database but need a way to do it other than manually with each one.

So I have a custom field for each post called `video_code` which equals the url of the video.

So with that I need to do something like this for all posts of a specific post_type..

```
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
        require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$video_code = get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_code',true);
$video_id = getVideoId($video_code); // getVideoId is a custom function
if ($video_id) {
     $video_image_url = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$video_id.'/hqdefault.jpg';
     ut$tmp = download_url($video_image_url);
     $file_array = array(
                'name' => basename( $video_image_url ),
                'tmp_name' => $tmp
              );

}
$vid_thumb = media_handle_sideload( $file_array, $post_id );
update_post_meta($post_id,'video_thumb',$vid_thumb);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will fire on `init` so you just need to refresh a page one time for it to work. I left out the actual value of `$new_value` -- you need to define that.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_75308_update_video_meta' );

function wpse_75308_update_video_meta() {
    // Get all posts
    $posts = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => -1 );

    // Loop through each and update the custom field where it exists
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        update_post_meta( $post-ID, 'video_thumb', $new_value );
    }
}
```

Comment: So I refresh the homepage once and this fires? And if the page is refreshed again it refires?

Comment: Yeah, so firing it over and over will just update the meta again and again. So you just run it once, check that it worked and remove it.

Comment: What about the fact that I'm running media_handle_sideload()? It's just gonna download all those images with the code I have above? Do I need to require anything else?

Comment: Haven't you already uploaded all of the videos? Why do you need to upload them again?

Comment: I'm not uploading the videos. I'm downloading the video's thumb from the videos url.

Comment: I meant the images. The bottom line is that you'd be best off copying your DB, running this script and if it breaks tweaking it. You get a retry on every refresh so you can't *really* break anything.

Comment: I get an error saying "Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in" I the proper media files which I updated my example above with to reflect. Any idea why that is?